# Associate a title to columns in a data set

Tags: output-formatting, dataset

I am using a dataset to construct a matrix, how can I add the title Mass in kilograms above the Earth and Moon like in the table. [image]

Here is the code I am working on.

```
Dataset[
  <|"Earth planet and Moon" ->
      <|"Earth" -> <|"Earth" -> Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"]^2,
        "Moon" ->
          Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"] * 
            Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"]|>,
    "Moon" ->
      <|"Earth" ->
          Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"] * 
            Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"], 
        "Moon" -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"]^2|>|>|>]
```

When I try to make it a data set I only get the "Earth planet and Moon Mass" like the image below.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by “just like with the rows”? It does not appear that the code you posted matches to the output you show in the image.

Comment: I updated the question. I can only manage to insert the "Earth planet and Moon" to the dataset. How can I add the title "Mass in kilograms" above Earth and Moon.

Comment: Could be something like this: `Dataset@
 <|  <|"Earth planet and Moon" ->   <|"Earth" -> <| <|     "Mass in kg" -> <|"Earth" -> 3.57 kg ^2, "Moon" -> 4.387 kg^2|>|>|>,  "Moon" -> <|<| "Mass in kg" -> <|{"Earth" -> 4.387 kg^2,  "Moon" -> 4.387 kg^2}|>|>|>     |> |>|>`.

Comment: I have failed to locate what the question is. I'm confused...

Comment: @GustavoDelfino the question is how to achieve the formatting shown. I am sure it should be possible, but it seemingly is a frustrating organizational format according to Dataset—it is not trivial to show how this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

`Dataset` doesn't seem to give the kind of control over formatting that you want, but `Grid` does, so I recommend using it for display. You can still use the dataset to store data. ALso, since the key `"Earth planet and Moon"` only function is to serve as a label, I would remove the 1st level association from you dataset—reverting it back to the way you oringinally posted it. This will simplify references to data values in queries and in the display code.

```
ds =
  Dataset[
    {<|"Earth" ->
         <|"Earth" -> Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"]^2, 
           "Moon" -> 
             Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"] * 
             Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"]|>, 
       "Moon" -> 
         <|"Earth" -> 
             Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"] * 
             Entity["Planet", "Earth"]["Mass"], 
           "Moon" -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"]["Mass"]^2|>|>}]
```

[image: data]

I have also made some changes to the grid's options. I think they improve the way it looks.

```
With[{gray = GrayLevel[.95]},
  Grid[
    {{"", "", "Product of Masses", SpanFromLeft}, 
     {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromAbove, "Earth", "Moon"},
     {"Earth planet\nand Moon", Item["Earth", Frame -> True],
      ds[1, "Earth", "Earth"], ds[1, "Earth", "Moon"]},
     {SpanFromAbove, Item["Moon", Frame -> True],
      ds[1, "Moon", "Earth"], ds[1, "Moon", "Moon"]}},
    BaseStyle -> Directive["SR"],
    Dividers -> {{{True, False, {True}, -1 -> True}}, All},
    Background -> 
      {None, None, {{{1, 4}, {1, 2}} -> gray, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} -> gray}}]]
```

[image: grid]

Comment: Seems like this is for now the only way.